# Integrate ESLint with MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017, eslint

I know VS2017 now natively supports ESLint which is working fine for me. I need to know if is it possible to integrate ESLint with MSBuild so that I can have the same linting experience not only on my development workstation but on TFS CI/CD system too? Looks like there are some supported integrations as mentioned [here](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/integrations) but nothing on MSBuild.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to know if is it possible to integrate ESLint with MSBuild so
>   that I can have the same linting experience not only on my development
>   workstation but on TFS CI/CD system too?

So far, MSBuild does not integrate **ESLint**.

**Besides**, l found no official MSBuild document about Integrating ESLint. Also, I did a small test for Build Tool for VS2017, l found that there is no such component called ESLint which proves that it is not supported by MSBuild.(l also did in Build Tool in VS2019 and it is the same as in Build Tool for VS2017)

[image]

**In addition**, although MSBuild does not support **ESLint**, I think your proposal is an interesting idea and you can suggest a feature to user voice([DC Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html)).

After that, you can put the link here and we who interested in this will vote it so that it will call the attention of the Support Team.

Hope it could help you.